# pandas str.split() and retrieve the second value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe. Note that column 'score' has several numbers separated by commas, and in some instances (but not all), those individual numbers have letters associated with it to indicate something. Sometimes it could be no letters, or one to 3 letters:

```
{'index': {0: 0, 1: 1},
 'person': {0: 'jane', 1: 'karl'},
 'day': {0: 0, 1: 2},
 'score': {0: '20 M B, 25, 21', 1: '40, 43, 45'}}
```

I'd like to do two things. Firstly, have each number in score in its own row, and I can achieve this by a string split and then exploding the dataframe:

```
df['score'] = df['score'].str.split(", ")
df=df.explode('score')
```

Giving me the following dataframe:

```
{'index': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1},
 'person': {0: 'jane', 1: 'jane', 2: 'jane', 3: 'karl', 4: 'karl', 5: 'karl'},
 'day': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2},
 'score': {0: '20 M B', 1: '25', 2: '21', 3: '40', 4: '43', 5: '45'}}
```

To get those M and B letters into their own column, to be associated with that row (as I want scores to be numeric only, I can do the following:

```
df['notes'] = df['score'].str.split(' ', 1, expand=True)[1]
df['score'] = df['score'].str.split(' ', 1, expand=True)[0]
```

This gives me the following dataframe, which is exactly as expected:

```
{'index': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1},
 'person': {0: 'jane', 1: 'jane', 2: 'jane', 3: 'karl', 4: 'karl', 5: 'karl'},
 'day': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2},
 'score': {0: '20', 1: '25', 2: '21', 3: '40', 4: '43', 5: '45'},
 'notes': {0: 'M B', 1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None, 5: None}}
```

BUT, if the scores column does not have any letters in it (see df below), I get the error "ValueError: 1 is not in range" and "KeyError: 1". This makes sense as there is only one value, but how do I get around this, particularly thinking about reducing repetition of code?

```
{'index': {0: 0, 1: 1},
 'person': {0: 'jane', 1: 'karl'},
 'day': {0: 0, 1: 2},
 'score': {0: '20, 25, 21', 1: '40, 43, 45'}}
```

Comment: Assign `df['score'].str.split(' ', 1, expand=True)` to a variable, then you can use `np.where()` to conditionalize the assignment to `df['notes']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use your original logic, just [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) the output of `split` to ensure having two columns and assign both score/note at once:

```
df['score'] = df['score'].str.split(", ")
df = df.explode('score')
df[['score', 'note']] = (df['score']
                         .str.split(' ', n=1, expand=True)
                         .reindex(columns=[0, 1])
                        )
```

Or, if you only want the "note" column if there is at least one non-NaN value, use a conditional:

```
df['score'] = df['score'].str.split(", ")
df = df.explode('score')

tmp = df['score'].str.split(' ', n=1, expand=True)
df['score'] = tmp[0]
if 1 in tmp:
    df['note'] = tmp[1]
```

##### alternative approach

Instead of using `split` and `explode` you could craft a regex to identify the score (digits = `\d+`) and optionally another string (without comma) using [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html). Then [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to the original DataFrame:

```
out = (df.drop(columns=['score'])
         .join(df['score']
               .str.extractall(r'(?P<score>\d+)(?: (?P<note>[^,]+))?')
               .droplevel('match')
              )
      )
```

Or to modify the original DataFrame:

```
df = df.join(df.pop('score')
               .str.extractall(r'(?P<score>\d+)(?: (?P<note>[^,]+))?')
               .droplevel('match')
            )
```

Output (example 1):

```
   index person  day score note
0      0   jane    0    20  M B
0      0   jane    0    25  NaN
0      0   jane    0    21  NaN
1      1   karl    2    40  NaN
1      1   karl    2    43  NaN
1      1   karl    2    45  NaN
```

Output (example 2):

```
   index person  day score note
0      0   jane    0    20  NaN
0      0   jane    0    25  NaN
0      0   jane    0    21  NaN
1      1   karl    2    40  NaN
1      1   karl    2    43  NaN
1      1   karl    2    45  NaN
```

###### regex

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/POOglb/1)

```
(?P<score>\d+)         # match one or more digits, name the group "score"
(?: (?P<note>[^,]+))?  # optional match any character but "," after a space, name the group "note"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function:

```
def split_score(s):
    parts = s.split(' ', 1)
    return parts if len(parts) > 1 else [parts[0], None]
```

and applied it on each row:

```
df[['score', 'notes']] = df['score'].apply(lambda x:pd.Series(split_score(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

use following code:

```
out = (df.assign(score=df['score'].str.split(", ")).explode('score')
         .assign(note=lambda x: x['score'].str.split(' ', n=1).str[1])
         .assign(score=lambda x: x['score'].str.split(' ', n=1).str[0]))
```

**Example Code**

case1.

```
data = {'index': {0: 0, 1: 1},
 'person': {0: 'jane', 1: 'karl'},
 'day': {0: 0, 1: 2},
 'score': {0: '20 M B, 25, 21', 1: '40, 43, 45'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

out:

```
   index person  day score note
0      0   jane    0    20  M B
0      0   jane    0    25  NaN
0      0   jane    0    21  NaN
1      1   karl    2    40  NaN
1      1   karl    2    43  NaN
1      1   karl    2    45  NaN
```

case2.

```
data1 = {'index': {0: 0, 1: 1},
 'person': {0: 'jane', 1: 'karl'},
 'day': {0: 0, 1: 2},
 'score': {0: '20, 25, 21', 1: '40, 43, 45'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

out

```
   index person  day score  note
0      0   jane    0    20   NaN
0      0   jane    0    25   NaN
0      0   jane    0    21   NaN
1      1   karl    2    40   NaN
1      1   karl    2    43   NaN
1      1   karl    2    45   NaN
```